# ¿Cómo hago para mostrar con un mesh?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

Hice esto:

```
Gizmos.color = Color.yellow;
Gizmos.DrawLine(startingPosition, position);
```

Lo puedo ver en el editor pero no sé cómo hacer para verlo en el renderizado, o sea, cuando pruebo el juego. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la vista de juego, en la parte superior derecha, tienes un desplegable donde puedes habilitar los Gizmos para esa vista concreta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]